# VBA application.Ontime TimeValue does not run

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get a report done and sent out at 7:00am everyday. I put Application.Ontime TimeValue("7:00:00"), "DailyReport" in my code. This ran fine in the past, but after I modified some other codes in DailyReport sub (which should not affect Application.Ontime anyway) and check "Ignore other application using DDE", the report does not fire at 7:00am anymore.

Any help is greatly appreciated, guys!!!!

```
Option Explicit

Sub DailyReport()
Dim t As String 'Time to send daily Snapshot
Dim pr As Boolean 'Is process running/is there data for yesterday


ThisWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:="Y:\DATA COLLECTION 2018.xlsx"
Application.Calculate
t = Db.Range("C6").Value()
pr = Db.Range("D5").Value()
Db.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.Refresh
Db.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Chart.Refresh
Db.ChartObjects("Chart 4").Chart.Refresh


Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objMail As Object
Dim rng As Range

    today = Format(Now(), "m/dd/yyyy")

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
    Set rng = Db.Range("B8:F16")

    Dim myPic1 As String
    Dim myPic2 As String
    Dim myPic3 As String
    Dim fileName1 As String
    Dim fileName2 As String
    Dim fileName3 As String
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim sj As String

    myPic1 = "Feed.png"
    myPic2 = "T and Vacuum.png"
    myPic3 = "D.png"
    myPath = "C:\Users\lab3\Downloads\"

    fileName1 = myPath & myPic1
    fileName2 = myPath & myPic2
    fileName3 = myPath & myPic3
    Db.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.Export fileName1
    Db.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Chart.Export fileName2
    Db.ChartObjects("Chart 4").Chart.Export fileName3

    With objMail
        Dim cell As Range
        Dim strto As String

        For Each cell In Distribution.Range("A1:A100")
            If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then
                strto = strto & cell.Value & ";"
            End If
        Next cell

        If Len(strto) > 0 Then strto = Left(strto, Len(strto) - 1)
        If pr Then sj = "Daily Report " & today Else sj = "Daily Report " & today & " - No new data"
            .To = strto
            .Subject = sj
            .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng) & "<p><p>" & "<img src = '" & fileName1 & "'>" & "<p><p>" & _
            "<img src = '" & fileName3 & "'>" & "<p><p>" & "<img src = '" & fileName2 & "'>"
            .Display

   End With


With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
     End With

    Application.SendKeys "%s"

    Set objOutlook = Nothing
    Set objMail = Nothing


Db.Range("C5").FormulaR1C1 = "TRUE"
Application.StatusBar = "Ready"
ThisWorkbook.Save
Application.OnTime TimeValue("7:00:00"), "DailyReport", True

End Sub
```

Comment: `but after I modified some other codes in DailyReport sub` what code did you modify exactly? Please update your question to let us know.

Answer (score -1):

From documentatation of  (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-ontime-method-excel) :

> Set Schedule to false to clear a procedure previously set with the same Procedure and EarliestTime values.